# Is there a way I can use an input to determine the clock period?

Tags: verilog, clock, vivado, test-bench

This program needs to be able to output a sinewave to the testbench, where the frequency of the output signal should be specified by an eight bit
input. My understnading is that I need to change the clock period which will alter the frequency of the waveform accordingly.The code is provided below:

```
module functionGenerator(Clk,data_out, freq);
//declare input and output
    input [7:0] freq;
    input Clk;
    output [9:0] data_out;
//declare the sine ROM - 30 registers each 8 bit wide.  
    reg [9:0] sine [0:99];
//Internal signals  
    integer i;  
    reg [9:0] data_out;
//Initialize the sine rom with samples. 
    initial begin
        i = 0;
        sine[0] = 0;        sine[1] = 10;        sine[2] = 20;        sine[3] = 29;        sine[4] = 39;   
        sine[5] = 48;       sine[6] = 58;        sine[7] = 67;        sine[8] = 75;        sine[9] = 84;
        sine[10] = 92;      sine[11] = 100;      sine[12] = 107;      sine[13] = 114;      sine[14] = 120;
        sine[15] = 126;     sine[16] = 132;      sine[17] = 137;      sine[18] = 141;      sine[19] = 145;   
        sine[20] = 149;     sine[21] = 151;      sine[22] = 153;      sine[23] = 155;      sine[24] = 156;
        sine[25] = 156;     sine[26] = 156;      sine[27] = 155;      sine[28] = 153;      sine[29] = 151;
        sine[30] = 149;     sine[31] = 145;      sine[32] = 141;      sine[33] = 137;      sine[34] = 132;   
        sine[35] = 126;     sine[36] = 120;      sine[37] = 114;      sine[38] = 107;      sine[39] = 100;
        sine[40] = 92;      sine[41] = 84;       sine[42] = 75;       sine[43] = 67;       sine[44] = 58;
        sine[45] = 48;      sine[46] = 39;       sine[47] = 29;       sine[48] = 20;       sine[49] = 10;   
        sine[50] = 0;       sine[51] = -10;      sine[52] = -20;      sine[53] = -29;      sine[54] = -39;
        sine[55] = -48;     sine[56] = -58;      sine[57] = -67;      sine[58] = -75;      sine[59] = -84;
        sine[60] = -92;     sine[61] = -100;     sine[62] = -107;     sine[63] = -114;     sine[64] = -120;   
        sine[65] = -126;    sine[66] = -132;     sine[67] = -137;     sine[68] = -141;     sine[69] = -145;
        sine[70] = -149;    sine[71] = -151;     sine[72] = -153;     sine[73] = -155;     sine[74] = -156;
        sine[75] = -156;    sine[76] = -156;     sine[77] = -155;     sine[78] = -153;     sine[79] = -151;   
        sine[80] = -149;    sine[81] = -145;     sine[82] = -141;     sine[83] = -137;     sine[84] = -132;
        sine[85] = -126;    sine[86] = -120;     sine[87] = -114;     sine[88] = -107;     sine[89] = -100;
        sine[90] = -92;     sine[91] = -84;      sine[92] = -75;      sine[93] = -67;      sine[94] = -58;
        sine[95] = -48;     sine[96] = -39;      sine[97] = -29;      sine[98] = -20;      sine[99] = -10;
    end

    //At every positive edge of the clock, output a sine wave sample.
    always@ (posedge(Clk))
    begin
        data_out = sine[i];
        i = i+ 1;
        if(i == 99)
            i = 0;
    end

endmodule
```

Testbench

```
module functionGeneratror_tb();

    // Inputs
    reg Clk;
    reg freq;

    // Outputs
    wire [9:0] data_out;

    // Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
    functionGenerator uut (
        .Clk(Clk), 
        .data_out(data_out),
        .freq(freq)
    );

    //Generate a clock with 10 ns clock period.
    initial Clk = 0;
    always #5 Clk = ~Clk; // CAN I PASS IN AN INPUT HERE INSTEAD OF 5?
    initial
    #10000 $finish;

endmodule
```

Comment: Use a counter to divide the clock to control the frequency. Highest frequency would be to divide the clock by 1, lowest frequency would be to divide the clock by 255.

Comment: By the way: in HDL you normally store only 1/4 of the complete sine table. The other quadrants are derived by subtraction and using a negative operator.

Answer (score 0):

```
always #5 Clk = ~Clk;
```

This statement is part of your testbench, not part of the UUT. You aren't supposed to change it; the expectation is that the clock frequency remains constant.

Your `functionGenerator` module currently doesn't make any use of the `freq` input. You will need to come up with some way to control how quickly the synthesizer steps through the `sine` array based on the value of `freq`. This may involve either making less than one step per `clk` period, or making multiple steps per period, depending on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical case in which a phase-acummulator oscillator is used to generate the ROM address for the new sample to output.

Something like this: the phase accumulator here is 14 bits wide, and we are using the 6 most significant bits to have a sine wave of 64 samples. The output frequency of such sine wave is CLK * freq / 16384

Actually, the ROM has only 16 cells, as it needs only to store one quarter of a sine wave. Bits 3 to 0 from the calculated address from the phase accumulator are used to address the ROM, and bits 5 to 4 are used to find out which quadrant we are in, so the actual address may need to be inverted and/or the actual output may need to be negated.

```
module FunctionGenerator (
  input wire clk,
  input wire [7:0] freq, // frequency of output signal is: clk * freq / 16384
  output reg signed [9:0] out
  );

  reg signed [9:0] quartersin[0:15];
  // Generate initial values with this little C program:
  //   #include <stdio.h>
  //   #include <math.h>
  // 
  //   #define PI 3.141592654
  // 
  //   int main()
  //   {
  //     int i;
  //     
  //     for (i=0;i<16;i++)
  //     {
  //         printf ("    quartersin[%2d] = %d;\n", i, (int)(511*sin(i*2*PI/64.0)));
  //     }
  //
  //     return 0;
  //   }
  initial begin
    quartersin[ 0] = 0;
    quartersin[ 1] = 50;
    quartersin[ 2] = 99;
    quartersin[ 3] = 148;
    quartersin[ 4] = 195;
    quartersin[ 5] = 240;
    quartersin[ 6] = 283;
    quartersin[ 7] = 324;
    quartersin[ 8] = 361;
    quartersin[ 9] = 395;
    quartersin[10] = 424;
    quartersin[11] = 450;
    quartersin[12] = 472;
    quartersin[13] = 488;
    quartersin[14] = 501;
    quartersin[15] = 508;
  end

  reg [13:0] phaseacum = 14'h0000;
  reg [3:0] indx;
  always @(posedge clk) begin
    phaseacum <= phaseacum + {6'b000000, freq};
    if (phaseacum[13] == 1'b0)  // if in quadrants 0 or 1, out as is
      out <= quartersin[indx];
    else
      out <= -quartersin[indx];  // if in quadrants 2 or 3, negate out
  end

  always @* begin
    if (phaseacum[12] == 1'b0)   // which quadrant am I ?
      indx = phaseacum[11:8];  // if in quadrant 0 or 2
    else
      indx = ~phaseacum[11:8]; // else, in quadrant 1 or 3
    endcase
  end
endmodule
```

A minimal testbench can be used to let this function generator to run for a thousand or so clock cycles, and then take the output to GTKWave and display it as an analog output:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ns

module tb;
  reg clk;
  reg [7:0] freq;
  wire [9:0] out;

  FunctionGenerator uut (
    .clk(clk),
    .freq(freq),
    .out(out)
  );

  initial begin
    $dumpfile("dump.vcd");
    $dumpvars(1,uut);

    clk = 1'b0;
    freq = 8'd16;  // aprox. 1 kHz sine wave for a 1 MHz clk

    repeat (2000) begin
      @(posedge clk);
    end
    $finish;
  end

  always begin
    clk = #500 ~clk;  // a 1 MHz clock
  end
endmodule
```

This is the result, simulated with iverilog / GTKWave:

[image: GTKWave simulated output]